# Azure app service plan selection multiple vs one plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

What is the best practice regarding App service plans. Is it best practice to have one App service and allow it to auto scale til capacity
Or is it normal practice to seperate some critical applications into their own app service. Microsoft has some recommendations. But want to know the general practice

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Regards,
Ujjwal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have a multi-tier application, then you could consider separating the different tiers in different app service plans, so you can scale them independently according to the workload. One important detail to keep in mind is that if you have a single App Service plan for all your application(s), then the one or many applications under the same plan will share the same resources. If you want to leverage autoscale feature, and considering that your applications have different usage patterns, then again it would be good to have each app running on a separate app service plan, so you can scale just when it is necessary and just for that individual app.

Comment: also consider checking this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture#controlling-density